# apply inside apply function?

Tags: r, apply, google-analytics-api

I've a data frame with the start and end of each month of the year 2019.

I need to make a fetch to an API, write a CSV file with name `mydf` plus month (eg. `mydf-01.csv`, `mydf-02.csv`, etc).

I need to fetch the data, write CSV, clean memory to avoid error message "not enough memory", and continue with the next month.

For now I've this, but is giving me error: not enough memory, because the expected data for all 2019 is around 3GB.

I was thinking on making a for loop. But maybe I can use another apply family function?

**Months: my_dates data.frame**

*This is how it looks:*

```
from        to
2019-01-01  2019-01-31
2019-02-01  2019-02-28
2019-03-01  2019-03-31
...
```

*Code to generate the 12 months:*

```
som <- function(x) as.Date(cut(as.Date(x), "month")) # start of month
eom <- function(x) som(som(x) + 32) - 1 # end of month

month_ranges <- function(from, to) {
  s <- seq(som(from), as.Date(to), "month")
  data.frame(from = pmax(as.Date(from), s), to = pmin(as.Date(to), eom(s)))
}

my_dates <- month_ranges(som("2019-01-01"), eom("2019-12-31"))
```

**Code to fetch data:**

> Currently it fetches all months, holds them in memory and at the end
>   it rbinds them together. However, this approache gives error when
>   months range is too large because data is above 2GB. So I'd like it for each month to save the data to > a CSV and continue to the next month.

```
library(googleAuthR)
library(googleAnalyticsR)

my_fetch <- function(ga_id, d1, d2) {
  google_analytics(ga_id,
                   date_range = c(d1, d2),
                   metrics = c("totalEvents"),
                   dimensions = c("ga:date", "ga:eventCategory", "ga:eventAction", "ga:eventLabel"),
                   anti_sample = TRUE,
                   anti_sample_batches = 1,
                   rows_per_call = 400)
}


my_fetches_fetches <- mapply(my_fetch, myviewID, my_dates$from, my_dates$to, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)


total <- do.call(rbind, my_fetches_fetches)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Maybe it could be possible to pass the "loop" that generates an error, like API timeout to continue to the next month?

Comment: The easiest thind to do would be store the result of `google_analytics()` and write it to a csv in the function itself like : `df<-google_analytics(...) ; write.csv(df,'myfile.csv',append=T)`

Comment: @Rohit how to handle any error? Like if the googe_analytics() returns a 503 for a particular query, but you want to continue with the next one?

Comment: What does your function do in this case? Does it throw an error, does it return a null value? If it throws an error, the you can use `trycatch()`. Otherwise, just use an if-else to decide whether or not to write to file.